# Fusion charts npm , how to upgrade to licensed version

Tags: fusioncharts

I was using FusionCharts to build some charts.Now that i know how to integrate it using npm I want to upgrade to a commercial license for my client. I didn't see any documentation specific to npm version.
The documentation on official website points to [Fusion charts npm installation](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/installing-via-npm-and-bower/installing-via-npm.html) but there is no mention of how to upgrade to licensed version.

Comment: did you find any documentation?

Comment: drop a mail to support@fusioncharts.com, they will help you with this

Because sharing the steps to add license files will not be disclosed in the open forum.

Comment: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/upgrading/license-activation

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is really lacking in this regard, that's a shame. After reading tons of stuff, that's what I came up, in Angular 7:

1. Removed the npm package `fusioncharts`, but kept `"angular-fusioncharts": "^3.0.1"`
2. Created a folder `libs` in the root of my project, then put inside this folder the content downloaded from the link in the purchase email, renaming to `fusioncharts`
3. Changed my imports from:

```
    import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts'
    import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts'
    import * as PowerCharts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.powercharts'
    import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion'
```

to

```
    import * as FusionCharts from 'libs/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts'
    import * as Charts from 'libs/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.charts'
    import * as PowerCharts from 'libs/fusioncharts/js/fusioncharts.powercharts'
    import FusionTheme from 'libs/fusioncharts/js/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion'
```

4. The init code was the same:

   `FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, PowerCharts, FusionTheme)`

---

I don't understand why I was getting an error if I kept the `import * as FusionTheme` for the theme package, I had to change to `import FusionTheme from`.

I put `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in my `tsconfig.json` at some point during this process, not sure if this configuration is needed for this last step.

Some (not that) useful links:

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angular/configure-your-chart-using-angular

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/upgrading/upgrading-from-evaluation-versions

Comment: if you are getting any issue with angular-fusioncharts ngcc failed try with angular-fusioncharts:3.0.4